# Javascript Menu

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css

```
<script>
function HideandUNhideObj(ThisObj) {
var nav = document.getElementById(ThisObj).style
if (nav.display == "none") {
nav.display = 'block';
} else {
nav.display = 'none';
}
}
</script>

<ul class="removebullet">
<li>
<div onclick="HideandUNhideObj('div1');">Head</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="div1">
<ul class="removebullet">
<li><a>Submenu1</a></li>
<li><a >Submenu2</a></li>
<li><a >Submenu3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

On "Head" Click it shows submenus...
How do i save this menu position after redirect in other pages?thanks

Comment: Don't build your menu with obtrusive JavaScript. There are a lot of ways of doing nice menus without it.

Comment: @ErickPetru Might be helpful for you to mention what obtrusive JavaScript is if you are going to comment in passing without answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a modern browser, you could use localStorage.
Learn about it at http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) or [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using HTML5 local storage: http://jsfiddle.net/ryancook/99oqp1oy/

Just refresh your browser to see that it remembers if the submenu is open or closed.

```
function saveMenu (show) {
    if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
        if (show) {
            localStorage.submenu = 'show';
        } else {
            localStorage.submenu = 'hide';
        }
    }
}

function restoreMenu () {
    if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
        if (localStorage.submenu === 'show') {
            HideandUNhideObj('div1');
        }
    }
}

function HideandUNhideObj(ThisObj) {
    var nav = document.getElementById(ThisObj).style;
    if (nav.display == "none") {
        nav.display = 'block';
        saveMenu(1);
    } else {
        nav.display = 'none';
        saveMenu(0);
    }
}

restoreMenu();
```

You will need to move your JavaScript to the bottom of your HTML body (see the fiddle), unless you restructure your JavaScript to wait for the DOM to load, but I took the approach that is closest to your existing code.